# Java Jackson: why do I get JsonMappingException although I used @JsonDeserialize

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I need some help with Jackson library in Java. I have the following class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
public class MarketHistoryData {
    private String countryCode;
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = BpTimeDeserializer.class)
    private Map<BpTime, Double> hourToExpectedEngagePaidListings;
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = BpTimeDeserializer.class)
    private Map<BpTime, Double> hourMinuteToExpectedEngagePaidListings;

    public MarketHistoryData() {}
    ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

I understood that Jackson has difficulties with deserializing a map which its keys are an object. Therefore, I added the annotations:

```
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = BpTimeDeserializer.class)
```

The class BpTimeDeserializer is:

```
public class BpTimeDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

  private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public BpTime deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(key, BpTime.class);
  }
}
```

Still, I get an error during the deserialization process:

> *****.UncheckedExecutionException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized
> token 'com': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or
> token 'null', 'true' or 'false')  at [Source:
> (String)"****BpTime@5922062e[hour=1,minute=0]";
> line: 1, column: 1] (through reference chain:
> ***PacerCycleOutput["campaignIdToFactorComputationData"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["1011620661"]->****FactorComputationData["selectedMarketHistoryDataForCampaign"]->***MarketHistoryData["hourToExpectedEngagePaidListings"])

Do you know what I can do to overcome this error?

Comment: Could you include an example of the JSON? From the exception it looks like you have a non-valid JSON value in there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way how to resolve this error.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MarketHistoryData {
    private String countryCode;
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = BpTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = BpTimeSerializer.class)
    private Map<BpTime, Double> hourToExpectedEngagePaidListings;
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = BpTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = BpTimeSerializer.class)
    private Map<BpTime, Double> hourMinuteToExpectedEngagePaidListings;
    ...
}


public class BpTimeDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

  private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public BpTime deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    String[] keySplit = key.split(" ");
    BpTime bpTime = new BpTime();

    if (!keySplit[0].equals("-1")) {
      bpTime.setHour(Integer.parseInt(keySplit[0]));
    }
    if (!keySplit[1].equals("-1")) {
      bpTime.setMinute(Integer.parseInt(keySplit[1]));
    }
    return bpTime;
  }
}


public class BpTimeSerializer extends StdSerializer<BpTime> {

  public BpTimeSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public BpTimeSerializer(Class<BpTime> t) {
    super(t);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(BpTime value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException {
    generator.writeFieldName(String.format("%s %s", ofNullable(value.getHour()).orElse(-1),
        ofNullable(value.getMinute()).orElse(-1)));
  }
}
```